# how to open node in a new terminal from cmd?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd

when I type `start node` into the cmd it starts up a new node terminal like this:

[image]

but how do I get it to run a script in the node terminal and close it after it's done?

maybe something like this?

`start node "index.js"` (when I try this it opens a terminal then immediately closes)

index.js:

```
console.log('hello there!');

await new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r,3000));
```

Comment: You can't use top level await in 14.17.6 . It can be used in 14.18.0 as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top-level `await`s aren't supported in Node versions prior to 14.18.0; there is [a helpful discussion on GitHub as to why](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-await/issues/9).

Since you're running v14.17.6, you'll need to wrap your code in an anonymous `async` function, then invoke it with `()`:

```
(async () => {
    console.log('hello there!');
    await new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r,3000));
})();
```

The resulting Node terminal will `await` for your timeout period before being closed.

(It may also behoove those reading this answer to ensure that they are correctly referencing the script they wish to execute relative to their command line's current working directory; see comment below by @cakelover.)

Comment: They are supported since 14.18.0 I think.

Comment: ah yes I forgot about that, also the directory needed to be the complete directory `start node "C:\...\index.js"` can you add this as well so I can mark your answer as correct?

Comment: @Noob Thanks! Wasn't aware of this. I've added that context to my answer.